# Regular Expression to capture a TMatchCollection of Paragraphs (Using Delphi XE 6)

Tags: regex, delphi, delphi-xe6

I'm trying to capture a collection of paragraphs that look like those shown below.
I would like to capture each paragraph in a separate collection. I have figured out how to capture each line independently, but not the full paragraph.
I'm using PCRE engine.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. I think there are may be new lines/line breaks at the end of each line also...if that makes a difference.  Some paragraphs may be 5 lines long, or as short as 2 lines.

FORECAST VALID 04/0000Z 33.8N 77.3W
MAX WIND 85 KT...GUSTS 105 KT.
64 KT... 20NE 20SE 0SW 20NW.
50 KT... 40NE 50SE 20SW 40NW.
34 KT...100NE 110SE 70SW 60NW.

FORECAST VALID 04/1200Z 36.3N 74.4W
MAX WIND 90 KT...GUSTS 110 KT.
64 KT... 30NE 30SE 0SW 20NW.
50 KT... 50NE 50SE 30SW 40NW.
34 KT...100NE 110SE 80SW 70NW.

FORECAST VALID 05/0000Z 39.4N 70.2W
MAX WIND 60 KT...GUSTS 75 KT.
50 KT... 60NE 80SE 60SW 60NW.
34 KT...100NE 130SE 110SW 90NW.

Comment: Is it not as simple as `<regex>(\n<regex>)*`? That is, look for a single-line match, followed by any number of additional matches, separated by line breaks. You'll of course need to specify the option to allow multi-line matches.

Comment: It's very difficult to answer this based on the very vague description of the data. "I think there may be new lines/line breaks at the end of each line also" - well, are there or aren't there? We can't tell from here, and you're certainly in the position to determine that information. Is there actually a break (blank line) between the "paragraphs"? Does each "paragraph" literally start with 'FORECAST'?

Comment: Hi Rob,
Based on your comment, I looked into the * to see if I can make it work and I think I might have it.  It appears to be capturing the paragraph, but I'll do some more testing.
Here's what I've come up with: (do you see in potential pitfalls?)
(FORECAST|OUTLOOK)\s+VALID\s+\d{2}\/\d{4}Z\s+\d{2}\.\d{1}(N|S)\s+\d{2,3}\.\d{1}(E|W)(.)*\r\nMAX WIND\s+\d{2,3}\s+KT...GUSTS\s+\d{2,3}\s+KT.\r\n((\d{2})\s+[KT|FT]\D*(\d+)(\w{2})\s+(\d+)(\w{2})\s+(\d+)(\w{2})\s+(\d+)(\w{2}).\r\n)*

Comment: Is trying to do this by regex willful masochism, <g> or do you have to do it that way?  Do you have a text file or similar with all the forecasts in?  I ask because there should be much simpler ways to extract individual forecasts in Delphi than using regex.

Comment: Bryan, please look at your question. Is it formatted correctly? If not, then please [edit] your question to improve it. You might be interested in [the section of the help regarding code and preformatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). Currently, it looks like there are three *lines*, each starting with "Forecast." I assumed those three lines together formed a *paragraph*. The regex in your comment seems to indicate that what's shown in the question are really three paragraphs, each consisting of three to five lines.

Comment: Hi Rob, yes first time using this site and I did not format the data correctly.  Fixed it now.  There are 3 paragraphs separated by a blank line.  The regex I posted above does seem to work, so I will test it on several different files to see if there are any gotcha's

Comment: @Ken.  There is a line break or carriage return, but I'm not sure how to tell which, or both.  I'm just guessing but the regex I posted above has \r\n and it works, so does this mean there is a linebreak and a carriage return?

Comment: You can just put the text in any text editor (such as Notepad) and turn off word wrap. Do you end up with multiple lines for each "paragraph", or just one long line for each? Do they have blank lines between the "paragraphs"? (You could also use a hex viewer and look for pairs of `0D 0A` values, which is a carriage return/line feed (CR/LF) pair, or use an editor like Notepad++ that lets you view non-printable characters and would display the CR/LF pairs. (Yes, `\r\n` is a CR/LF pair using C-syntax.)

Comment: I just tried this and it seems to work also...and much less complicated.  Thanks for all the tips.

(^(FORECAST|OUTLOOK)(.+?\r\n)*)